# How can I limit the range of numbers which it is possible to write in the View in ASP.NET not using Validation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

Ok in my view I have a input field to insert a number like this one:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div>Number</div>
<input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

And I want to limit the range of this value between two numbers, now, the answer that someone would normally give me is to do this:

```
[Range(0, 249,
ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public byte Number { get; set; }
```

but **I don't want to do that**, what I really want is that the arrows in the Input field in the View literally do not let me put a number that exceeds a range or is low that another number.

So for example, if I keep pressing the up arrow to increase the number, when it has already reached the top of 249, if I keep pressing the arrows it should not be able to increase that number anymore, and likewise, if I try to press the down arrow, It should be able to go below zero or letting me enter a negative number.

How can I do this? I need to use a Script to do this or there is another option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do like this:

```
<input  asp-for="Number" class="form-control" min="0" max="249"/>
```

result:
[image]